# Extracting index from Grid.Row\Column DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I have the following Button:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding DrawXO}">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoardIndexConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}" Path="(Grid.Row)"></Binding>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}" Path="(Grid.Column)" ></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
```

and the following MultiValueConverter:

```
class BoardIndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How do I get the actual value of the Grid.Row\Column from a DependencyProperty in my command?:

```
class DrawXOCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var values = (object[])parameter;
        var row = (int)(values[0]);
        var column = (int)values[1];
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
```

Comment: So `var values = (object[])parameter;` doesn't work?

Comment: @Clemens I get an array of 'DependencyProperty.UnsetValue's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have seen Binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio, because the Button is not an ancestor element here.

Instead of `FindAncestor` you should use `Self` to use the Button as source object:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoardIndexConverter}">
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(Grid.Row)"/>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(Grid.Column)"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

---

Your converter may also be implemented a little safer:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is int && values[1] is int)
    {
        return new Tuple<int, int>((int)values[0], (int)values[1]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then check the command parameter like this:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var cell = parameter as Tuple<int, int>;

    if (cell != null)
    {
        var row = cell.Item1;
        var column = cell.Item2;
        ...
    }
}
```